# Objective Sharpie - Automated Binding of AWSCognito fails with "'AWSCore/AWSCore.h' file not found"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I'm trying to bind "AWSCognito" using Sharpie and Cocoapods using following command:

```
sharpie pod init -force ios AWSCognito && sharpie pod bind
```

It ran good but build was failed with following errors:

````
Parsing 1 header files...
While building module 'AWSCognito' imported from /private/var/folders/0r/y26zbgwn7kx_vn2gr8qjztlm0000gp/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/83195091ba274dc1817fbb79ea9f60ad.h:1:
In file included from :1:
In file included from _ usr /build/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognito/AWSCognito.framework/Headers/AWSCognito-umbrella.h:3:
In file included from _ _usr /build/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognito/AWSCognito.framework/Headers/AWSCognito.h:26:
_ _usr _/build/Release-iphoneos/AWSCognito/AWSCognito.framework/Headers/AWSCognitoService.h:19:9: fatal error:
'AWSCore/AWSCore.h' file not found
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
          ^
/private/var/folders/0r/y26zbgwn7kx_vn2gr8qjztlm0000gp/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/83195091ba274dc1817fbb79ea9f60ad.h:1:9: fatal error:
could not build module 'AWSCognito'
@import AWSCognito;
~~~~^~~~~~

Binding...
2 errors generated.
Error while processing /private/var/folders/0r/y26zbgwn7kx_vn2gr8qjztlm0000gp/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/83195091ba274dc1817fbb79ea9f60ad.h.

Submitting usage data to Xamarin...
Submitted - thank you for helping to improve Objective Sharpie!

Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: Clang failed to parse input and exited with code 1```
````

I can't figure out why and how do I solve this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, answer would be appreciated.